# How to copy an iOS 5.1 app including the storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I want to copy an iOS 5.0 app to a new app.  In the process I want to change the name of the app, and include the original Storyboard.

I can of course, copy and paste the entire project, but everything retains the same Project Name.  How can I change the Project Name?

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What problems are you having? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 1: Create new XCode project "My New Project" for your new app.

```
File -> New -> New Project
```

Step 2: Use XCode to "Add Files

```
File -> Add Files to "My New Project"
```

In the add files dialog, select all the files you want to add. You may have to do this more than once depending on how you have things organized in your old project. Be sure to check "Copy items into destination group's folder (if necessary)". Do NOT copy the old XCodeProject file (blue icon).

***Update:***

Storyboards are stored with a `.storyboard` extension. If you can't find it, it might not actually be in your XCode Project's folder in the filesystem. (I know I've lost things when trying a bunch of different things to copy resources between projects.) Open up your old project, locate the file in Xcode's Navigator Area, Option-Click it, and select "Show in Finder". Then you can copy it in from there. I was able to do this just now in XCode 4.2.

Comment: Thanks, but I've done this.  The add files dialog does not show the storyboard.  Hence I can't copy all the wiring of the app!

Comment: Well Thanks so much for that!  I am now officially Golly Goshilogged!  The file actually resides in the original project's folder called "en.lproj".  and that's what she wrote!

Comment: Thanks for the tip psoft. It worked great. Nice clean approach.